# Multiprocessing a function with several inputs

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In Python the `multiprocessing` module can be used to run a function over a range of values in parallel. For example, this produces a list of the first 100000 evaluations of f.

```
def f(i):
    return i * i

def main():
    import multiprocessing
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    ans = pool.map(f, range(100000))

    return ans
```

Can a similar thing be done when f takes multiple inputs but only one variable is varied? For example, how would you parallelize this:

```
def f(i, n):
    return i * i + 2*n

def main():
    ans = []
    for i in range(100000):
        ans.append(f(i, 20))

    return ans
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  In the example given in the question, you could just define a wrapper function

```
def g(i):
    return f(i, 20)
```

and pass this wrapper to `map()`.  A more general approach is to have a wrapper that takes a single tuple argument and unpacks the tuple to multiple arguments

```
def g(tup):
    return f(*tup)
```

or use a equivalent lambda expression: `lambda tup: f(*tup)`.

Answer (score 46):

You can use [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
def f(i, n):
    return i * i + 2*n

def main():
    import multiprocessing
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    ans = pool.map(functools.partial(f, n=20), range(100000))

    return ans
```

Comment: I know that this is allowed, but why, given that only functions defined at the module top level may be pickled?

Comment: Can you clarify moment about using partial - looks like it ignores keys for argument: if I want to pool.map on SECOND argument - `partial(f, i=20)` - I got error:  got multiple values for argument `i`.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

The function you are adding to the partial needs to have the first argument as the positional argument (like 'i' when running for loop) and the remaining keyword arguments should come after that. All the values of 'i' are added as a list/range as the second argument to the 'pool.map' function.

In your example, you have provided a value of 'i' within the partial function when the values for 'i' are already available as the second argument of 'pool' function, leading you to the self explanatory error/

Answer (score 8):

If you use my fork of `multiprocessing`, called `pathos`, you can get pools that take multiple arguments… and also take `lambda` functions.  The nice thing about it is that you don't have to alter your programming constructs to fit working in parallel.

```
>>> def f(i, n):
...   return i * i + 2*n
... 
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> N = 10000
>>>
>>> from pathos.pools import ProcessPool as Pool
>>> pool = Pool()
>>>
>>> ans = pool.map(f, xrange(1000), repeat(20))
>>> ans[:10]
[40, 41, 44, 49, 56, 65, 76, 89, 104, 121]
>>>
>>> # this also works
>>> ans = pool.map(lambda x: f(x, 20), xrange(1000))
>>> ans[:10]
[40, 41, 44, 49, 56, 65, 76, 89, 104, 121]
```

Comment: Just installed pathos - much nicer being able to use local functions with closures etc. without any global partials or wrapper funcs or anything else. Thanks for this.

Comment: @AlexL: note that if you want exactly the same interface as `multiprocessing` but with better serialization, you can alternately use `multiprocess` (`pathos` installs it as a dependency).

Answer (score 4):

This technique is know as Currying: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Another way to do it without using `functools.partial` using the classical `map` command inside `pool.map`:

```
def f(args):
   x, fixed = args
   # FUNCTIONALITY HERE

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1)
pool.map(f, map(lambda x: (x, fixed), arguments))
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use poor man's currying (aka wrap it):

```
new_f = lambda x: f(x, 20)
```

then call `new_f(i)`.

Comment: Thils will *not* work with multiprocessing's map, because that doesn't support functions that aren't "importable" (using the pickle tool)