# Multiprocessing.Pool for regular function?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have a functions that calculates millions lines of data and I what to make it faster with multiprocessing.
Before now i have used only `Pool` with `map` like that:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

pool = Pool(20)
pool.map(my_function, data_list)
```

But my function takes two parameters: list of companies and dictionary, with `csv` files as values in it.
So my question is, **How can I use multiprocessing with my function?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5442910/553404 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4463275/553404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the definition of `Pool.map()`:

```
def map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
```

From the view of semantics, the method `Pool.map()` just applies the function to an iterable, namely, the function must have and only have one variable argument which gets a value from the iterable. So the function must have only one argument or have a variable argument with other arguments having fixed values.

So there are a few solutions:

- Use **functools.partial()** function to *fix* other arguments in the function, which is described in [Python multiprocessing pool.map for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments)
- Use a list or tuple as the unique argument of the function, which encapsulates the arguments the function needs
- Don't use `Pool.map()`. Use `multiprocessing.Process()` to generate each process and then add them to the pool

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list to include all the arugments, then the function just takes the only one argument and parse the argument in the function.